# What's the origin of "Copycat"?

Tags: etymology, expressions

I called one of my friends "copycat" the other day, and suddenly thought about it.

Why is it a "cat"?  Where did this expression come from?

Does anyone have any information regarding how this phrase came about? Is there a story behind this?

Comment: This [article from Slate.com](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2011/08/what_a_copycat.html) has a good etymologic explanation.

Comment: Although these books use the expression, it seems that this phrase has actually already been in use, the way the author wrote it without putting "" around the word _copycat_, which seems to assume that the reader knows what the author is writing about.

Comment: I had the same thought when I asked my question about "moth hour" a while back. Its first published use by a poet must have meant it was already in use in the vernacular. That, it seems, is harder to track down.

Comment: @JLG, Incidentally the term is really *copy monkey* in Japanese

Comment: Alliteration plays a role here - consider "busybody".

Comment: Gee, it's so tempting to invent a story out of printing, where the kid who fetched the copy for the typesetter was called a "copy cat".

Answer (score 8):

The *cat* in *copy-cat* means *person*.

The *OED* says at **copy-cat** *n.*:

> Etymology: cat *n.*<sup>1</sup> 2.

the referenced sense being:

> **cat** *n.*<sup>1</sup> 2. *fig.* a. As a term of contempt for a human being; *esp.* one who scratches like a cat; a spiteful or backbiting woman. *spec.* an itinerant worker (*U.S. slang*).

Answer (score 4):

This is a slang term and was likely used in speech for a long time before being committed to the page, but the first print copy can still give us a rough idea of origin. [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=copycat&allowed_in_frame=0) tells us:

> **copycat (n.)**
>   by 1884, Amer.Eng., probably at least a generation older, from ***copy + cat***. As a verb, from 1932.

This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copy%20cat,copy%20-%20cat,copycat&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) tends to agree, with some instances before 1900, fairly constant use for most of the 20th century, but then a huge increase in the 1980s.

[image: Ngram of copy cat,copy-cat,copycat]

The OED's earliest citation is Jewett's 1896, so I've sent them the Harrison 1887 and Jewett 1890 antedatings from the Slate article.

An article in [Slate Magazine](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2011/08/what_a_copycat.html) tells us the term came from nineteenth-century Maine.

> Constance Cary Harrison's 1887 quasi-memoir *Bar Harbor Days* contains the first written evidence of the term copycat—that we know of, anyway. "Our boys say you are a copy cat, if you write in anything that's been already printed." Another early example comes from a different Maine-born writer, Sarah Orne Jewett, in her 1890 novel *Betty Leicester: A Story for Girls*. "I wouldn't be such a copy-cat," Lizzie French tells Betty, upon hearing that Betty wants to start a second all-girls club. Jewett used it again in her 1896 novel *Country of Pointed Firs*, about an elderly landlady in small-town coastal Maine who tells her friend Mrs. Fosdick, "In these days, the young folk is all copy-cats, 'fraid to death they won't be all just alike." Mrs. Fosdick's response suggests that the term had been part of the spoken vernacular for some time: "I ain't heard of a copy-cat this great many years," said Mrs. Fosdick, laughing; " 'twas a favorite term o' my grandmother's."

The *OED*'s earliest citation is Jewett's 1896, so I've sent them the Harrison 1887 and Jewett 1890 antedatings from Slate Magazine.

Comment: The OED's earliest citation is Jewett's 1896, so I've sent them the Harrison 1887 and Jewett 1890 antedatings from the Slate article.

Comment: Doug's 1884, could be [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=d44bAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA4-PA36&dq=%22copy-cat%22+-Bliss&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TC26T7KIAa_isQKN7I2LDA&ved=0CFEQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=copycat&f=false) which is actually from a 1914 annual report for the Dedham Library and not the original 1884 annual. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Eleanor_Wilkins_Freeman) confirms _The Copy-cat and Other Stories_ was published in 1914.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not good to call a friend a copycat, and if you do, etymology is your least concern
2. See this [Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2011/08/what_a_copycat.html) article regarding why it's not "copymonkey", etc., especially regarding the time of the origin of "hell-cat"
3. The origin of the term is unknown and likely unknowable at this point

Comment: "etymology is your poorest defence", rather?

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 cats who are sisters. One is a risk taker and very curious and the other much less so. The latter watches her sister when she is applauded for new behaviours and voila - within a day or 2 the 2nd sister is behaving in a similar way. We feel someone years ago saw this parallel behaviour too and coined the expression!!

Comment: According to the cited Slate article ["Unlike monkeys and parrots, cats aren't actually known for imitative behavior, but the term is somewhat logical since "cat" has been an insult since the medieval period."](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2011/08/what_a_copycat.html). In my limited experience, it's very difficult to train a cat to do tricks on command. :) Perhaps as Claire Lauzon has suggested, owners of two cats will have observed this behaviour in their pets.

Answer (score -1):

I have been thinking of this term 'copycat' for a while -  it could be an expression deriving from the previous saying:  'curiosity killed the cat' -  Since cats are very curious, one cat will follow another cat to see what it is doing or playing with and will no doubt copy/imitate its actions - ie; one cat plays with a small object.  Cat lovers who own two cats will certainly confirm this.

Answer (score -1):

There is a greater resemblance between 2 cats than any other kind of animal.

Comment: Not really. If you were talking about big cats, you might have a point but the variety of domestic cats is mind boggling.